# Updating SQL database using PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, sql-update

I am trying to make a password retrieval system on my site, and I am having problems updating the password reset field in my database. I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work.

This is my code so far:

```
$passwordreset = md5(mt_rand()) . md5(mt_rand()) . md5(mt_rand());

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","XXX","XXX");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

mysql_query("UPDATE members SET passwordreset = $passwordreset WHERE id = $id");
```

When I try to insert the data I get the error:

```
Error: Query was empty
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the message comes from this particular query? How do you get the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it's the only problem, but I'm guessing your passwordreset field is a string, in the database -- to store a concatenation of several md5, which are strings, it has to.

So, there should be quotes arround the value you put in this field, in the SQL query :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET passwordreset = '$passwordreset' WHERE id = $id");
```

And, in a general case, you should escape your string values with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET passwordreset = '" 
    . mysql_real_escape_string($passwordreset) 
    . "' WHERE id = $id");
```

It won't change anything here, as there is no quote in a md5... But it's a good practice to always do it, to never find yourself in a situation where it was necessary and you didn't do it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  still doesn't work, getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Are the two line breaks after `$passwordreset` intentional? Can you try removing them?

Comment: They shouldn't be a problem. I have lots of long MySQL statements here with line breaks and php / MySQL have no problems with them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if you get an empty query error for this, but you need ticks around the values:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET passwordreset = '$passwordreset' WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the backticks around the names of the columns are missing, try:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET `passwordreset` = '$passwordreset' WHERE `id` = '$id'");
```